# Equations of lines in triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

The vertices of the triangle $∆ABC$ are the intersection points of the lines
$d1 : 4x + 3y − 5 = 0$, $d2 : x − 3y + 10 = 0$, $d3 : x − 2 = 0$.
(a) Find the coordinates of $A, B, C$.
(b) Find the equations of the median lines of the triangle.
(c) Find the equations of the heights of the triangle.

Can somebody give me some tips on how should I solve these points, please?

Comment: For part (a), solve the systems of equations resulting from taking two equations at a time: $\{d1,d2\},\{d2,d3\},\{d3,d1\}$.

Comment: Part (b):  One of the medians is the line through point $A$ and the point midway between $B$ and $C$, etc.

Comment: Part (c):  One of the heights is the distance from point $A$ to the line joining $B$ and $C$.

Comment: From the several questions that you’ve posted here in short period of time, it appears that you’re lacking some basic understanding of linear equations and how to form them. A review of the course material that preceded this problem set that you’re working on appears to be in order.